# Why is simple Processing code crashing the browser?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

In p5.js I wrote this simple linear loop that draws lines between random points on the screen.

If I loop 99 999 times the screen displays instantly.

999 999 times and it takes ten seconds

9 999 999 it hangs the browser.

Why is this happening for a linear loop with a basic operation?  Is there something about the Processing lifecycle that I am not understanding?  Like when exactly is the canvas updated (each line or in batches or what)? Do I need to put my code in an async loop?

```js
function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(1920, 965, P2D);
    colorMode(HSL, 100); // hue saturation lightness
    noLoop();
    background(100,100,100,255); //solid white background           
    for (let i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
        drawLines()
}

function drawLines() 
{
    stroke(60, random(60,100), random(0,100), 255);
    const p1 = getRandomPoint();
    const p2 = getRandomPoint();
    line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
}

function getRandomPoint()
{
    return { x: random(0, width), y: random(0, height) };
}
```

Comment: You're probably just tying up the event thread, which will make the browser unresponsive. I don't write JS, but blocking in `setup` is likely not a good idea. Usually, you want to avoid blocking, and should rely on async code when possible.

Answer (score 0):

9999999 are just to many lines at once. Split drawing the lines:

```js
function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(1920, 965, P2D);
    colorMode(HSL, 100); // hue saturation lightness
    background(100,100,100,255); //solid white background       
}
 
function draw()
{  
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        drawLines()
    if (frameCount >= 9999)
        noLoop();     
}

function drawLines() 
{
    stroke(60, random(60,100), random(0,100), 255);
    const p1 = getRandomPoint();
    const p2 = getRandomPoint();
    line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
}

function getRandomPoint()
{
    return { x: random(0, width), y: random(0, height) };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just did this myself, but I still want to know *how* setup() draws. Why does it crash? Is it holding a buffer that gets too big, or is it the canvas that can't handle a single update of such size, what is happening...

Comment: @Richard Is it really crashing or is it just not terminating? Anyway, I think your question can only be answered by someone who knows the internals of p5.js.

Comment: Using Firefox's profiler I confirmed that the vast majority of CPU time is just spent in the p5.js Renderer2D.line function and that function doesn't do anything much besides call the basic line drawing functions on the built in CanvasRenderingContext2D. So I don't think there's anything special that p5.js is doing to affect this behavior, it's just the natural effect of if you increase the amount of work by an order of magnitude it increase the amount of time by an order of magnitude. And a browser may interpret a function spinning at 100% CPU for >100 seconds as a crash.